# Apache Superset virtual env installation issue with flask

Tags: python, pip, apache-superset

I am trying to install superset in virtual environment and running in python3.6.

`pip install superset`

The installation failed with the below error message

**ERROR: flask-jwt-extended 3.21.0 has requirement Flask>=1.0, but you'll have flask 0.12.4 which is incompatible.**

So, I upgraded the flask by

`pip install --upgrade flask`

which upgrade to the latest version.

After upgrading flask, I again tried installing superset. This time I got the same error.

Not only it complained about the flask but also the process uninstalled the flask.

**ERROR: flask-jwt-extended 3.21.0 has requirement Flask>=1.0, but you'll have flask 0.12.4 which is incompatible.
....
  Found existing installation: Click 7.0
    Uninstalling Click-7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Click-7.0
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Found existing installation: Flask 1.1.1
    Uninstalling Flask-1.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-1.1.1**

Comment: I'd try `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Great! Added as answer to make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to try to first `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` (this will update pip - Python's package installer) 
 and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which should install all packages needed for superset.